# Covariance Kernel of the fractional Gaussian field

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

I am right now reading about the fractional Gaussian field and there came up the following question: What is the covariance Kernel of the fractional Gaussian field on $\mathbb{R}^d$ defined as a random element of the topological dual space of the Schwartz space. I couldnt find the solution in the internet. With covariance Kernel I mean a function

$C:\mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that for the fracional gaussian field h and for all $\phi,\psi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)\subseteq\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ we have

$\mathbb{E}[h(\phi)h(\psi)]=\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\phi(x)C(x,y)\psi(y)dxdy$.

Any help or source would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A classification in the rotation and translation invariant case is given in the introductory part of the thesis by Ajay Chandra ["Construction and Analysis of a Hierarchical Massless Quantum Field Theory"](https://libraetd.lib.virginia.edu/public_view/2r36tx772). See in particular Prop 2.9.

It is not correct to think of the covariance kernel $C$ as a function $\mathbb{R}^d\times \mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^d$. It is a temperate distribution, i.e., it belongs to $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{2d})$. It has singular support on the diagonal $x=y$, so outside that diagonal it indeed corresponds to a function of the form constant times $\frac{1}{|x-y|^{2\kappa}}$. However, if $\kappa>\frac{d}{2}$ there is a complicated finite part to be taken to build a distribution from the function.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I read the recommended thesis. Unfortunately there is no explicit answer to my question. I really need the explicit term of the covariance function of the fractional Gaussian field in all cases (all dimentions and values of the Hurst parameter). Is there a chance that you (or somebody else) knows where to find that?